# GAS: How to convert [hh].mm.ss string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would need help converting a sheet columns, which contains string, to number and date.

I was able to convert the numbers using this code

```
sheet.getRange('D:W').activate();
sheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0');
```

but I'm having trouble with a column that contains [hh].mm.ss string.

Please find [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12BlYE8grmYbkK7AAGtK9e0qfj9oQmTHOgf34iI8gfKs/edit?usp=sharing) a sample sheet illustrating the issue.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet for troubleshooting?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please provide more details like the spreadsheet locale and some sample data. Please pay attention to how the data is shown both on the cells and on the formula bar as some time they aren't shown the same way.

Comment: I created a sheet with some cells filled in with the data to be converted into data [hh] .mm.ss format. thank you 
 [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12BlYE8grmYbkK7AAGtK9e0qfj9oQmTHOgf34iI8gfKs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I updated the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12BlYE8grmYbkK7AAGtK9e0qfj9oQmTHOgf34iI8gfKs/edit?usp=sharing). I found that it would be enough for me to replace the colon with . (time format is [hh].mm.ss)

Comment: What do you expect the vlaue to look like as a number? To you want to round it to full hours?

Answer (score 0):

The number formatting `Duration` works in such a way that you need to multiply it by the amount of hours in a day (24) in order to transform it to a number corresponding to the (rounded) amount of hours.

**Sample function for implementation in Apps Script:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange('F2:F6').setFormula("E2*24");
  sheet.getRange('F2:F6').setNumberFormat("#,##0");
}
```